# Input vs Output Iterator - naming conventions

Tags: c++, iterator, naming-conventions

I am just trying to wrap my head around what an *InputIterator* and *OutputIterator* in C++ actually are.  Now, until now, I always assumed that the definitions I have always known of **Input** and **Output** also applied to iterators.

So that means that *Input* is "to place into something", meaning you can write to the iterator, as in, put something *in* the iterator.

*Output* is "to put out somewhere" and that has always meant to me, to write to the screen or stick into a variable.

Now it turns out with our friends Iterators, it is the other way, an **InputIterator** is used for read-only access to a sequence of elements, which seems to be it should be called "Output", as you'd use this type of iterator to write the elements of a `std::vector<int>` to `std::cout` for example.

The **OutputIterator** turns out to be the one that is write-only access.

I wondered, if anyone can give a reasonable explanation for this, I find, rather odd, naming of iterator types?

Comment: Read the sections §24.1.1 and §24.1.2 (from C++03 Standard).

Comment: @Nawaz, good suggestion, but I don't own a copy of the standard.

Comment: Is it illegal to distribute the standard freely?

Comment: @Seth, afaik yes, as it is a document which you normally have to pay for.

Comment: @Tony: grab one of the draft versions

Comment: I don't understand how iterators differ here.  All references to input that I have ever seen in programming have referred to inputting from outside data sources *into* your program, and output refers to outputting data *from* your program.  It's the same with iterators.

Answer (score 10):

It's just a matter of convention. "Input" and "output" are understood as "from"/"to" with  respect to the environment, not with respect to your program; or in the other direction, as "into/out of" with respect to your program, not the environment.

So "input" gets something *from* the environment and makes it available to your program, like `istream` or `read`. "Output" puts something from your program back out into the environment, like `ostream` and `write`.

The iterators follow the same direction, an input iterator makes the data from a range available to your program, while the output iterator puts data from your program into a range.

---

The way you may be thinking is that "input" is *somebody else's* input that your program should want to write to. But I guess the wording presumes an egocentric programmer for whom their own program is the point of reference, not anyone (or everyone) in the environment.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: "Input" and "output" are understood with respect to _your program_, not with respect to _the environment_.

Comment: @ymett: that depends on whether "with respect" refers to "input from" or "input into" :-)

Comment: Input is into your program. Output is out of your program. As you say yourself _[your] program is the point of reference_.

Comment: @ymett: Or: "input is from the enviroment, output is to the environment" ... you can skin this cat either way. But you're right, this isn't consistent with my last statement. Hm, let me try and reword this.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear - I meant to emphasise the _in_ and the _out_ (in the sense of location, not direction), which can only refer to the program.

Answer (score 5):

An input iterator is a wrapper around an input stream.
An output iterator is a wrapper around an output stream.

(Admittedly, you can write other input/output iterators, but those are the examples that exist in the standard, in the form of `istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator`)

An input stream is one you read from (you get input), and thus, an input iterator is one you can get input from as well.

I agree, it can be somewhat unintuitive if you just consider them as iterators. But when you remember that they typically wrap a stream, it makes more sense.

You can create an `ostream_iterator` (which is an OutputIterator) around `std::cout`, for example.